# Invalid Workflow file GitHub Actions

Tags: node.js, json, github

I keep getting an error in github actions. It says "invalid workflow file. You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 3". Any suggestions?

```yaml
name: Run test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master/*

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16.x
          cache: 'npm'
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm test
```

Comment: This workflow file should be valid. However, defining the branch pattern `master/*` seams a bit strange. Can edit your question to provide more details when the error occurs and where exactly it is displayed.

Comment: I was following a lecture who had different branch names than me so I just switched it with my branch name. I removed /* from the name and it worked, thank you so much.